# Why do argc and argv work even if they are outside of the main function?

Tags: c, gcc

I accidentally made argc and argv work outside of the main function.

Here's the code that reproduces this 'bug' (compiled with gcc):

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(void);

int main(void)
{
    test();
}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("argc = %i\n", argc);
    printf("args:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("- %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("test called\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are getting undefined behaviour, because you are calling `test()` with the wrong number and type of arguments. It just so happens that on your system, those parameters are set to `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Compiler vendors are not required to check for undefined behavior on the part of the programmer. Compilers can assume there's no undefined behavior, and use that to make more efficient compiler code. Not worth reasoning about. The fact that this works is an accident. Your program is ill formed. You have violated a contract with the C standard and the compiler vendor.

Comment: See also, "How come when I shoot myself in the middle of a public square I sometimes wake up alive in a hospital?"

Comment: "sometimes"... now that is a statistic with an interesting method to gather....

Comment: Why did it work? Depending on the platform/ABI (Application Binary Interface), some parameters values may be passed in registers. If the `main` function does not change those register values before calling `test`, then `test` will see the original parameter values passed to `main`. This won't work on any platform/ABI that only passes parameters on the stack.

Comment: Add `printf( "hello world!\n" );` in `main()` before you call `test()` and see if it still "works"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As comments already hinted, it is not so much a case of
"I accidentally made argc and argv work",
but more of
"I made argc and argv work accidentally".

I.e. you did not stumble across something which works reliable,
instead your code only accidentally works in no reliable way.

The concept of "undefined behaviour" is an important one in C.
It pays to make yourself familiar with it. That can even be fun, e.g. read up on "nasal demons".
Most relevant for your case is that UB can, among other things, fiendishly deceive you into believing that your program works; I consider this to actually be the worst case of possible outcomes.

You end up with undefined behaviour for reasons as given in the comment by pmacfarlane:

> You are getting undefined behaviour, because you are calling test() with the wrong number and type of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of *worked* must be clarified. If your program is `p.exe` and you run

```
 p one other
```

and if it *works* it means that in `test` you need to get 3 parameters, one is `p.exe` the name of the program in `argv[0]`, and also `one` and `other`.

But you declared main as
int main(void);
so you are not receiving the arguments from the shell. Not in `main`, not in `test`

A program like this one

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\n\
\t%d arguments received! Your program is: \"%s\"\n\
\t%d more arguments were provided on the command line\n",
        argc, argv[0], argc-1);
    return 0;
}
```

would show as an example

```
        3 arguments received! Your program is: "C:\SO\p.exe"
        2 more arguments were provided on the command line
```

If you `p.exe` is run as above

`argc` and `argv[]` are just arguments in `test` in your code. Nothing will link them to values eventually typed on the command line. But at run time these parameters will have some address in memory and some content there, and your program can read it and even do not crash. You can even say it is *working* .